How to properly configure custom Gradle tasks in Kotlin DSL (KTS) with specific input/output directories?
I am currently working on an Android project using Kotlin DSL (KTS) for Gradle configuration, and I'm having trouble setting up a custom Gradle task to process some files. My goal is to create a task that takes a specific directory of text files as input, processes them, and writes the output to another directory.
Here is my current setup in build.gradle.kts:
tasks.register<Copy>("processTextFiles") {
    from("src/main/text") // Input directory
    into("build/processed-text") // Output directory
    include("**/*.txt") // Only include text files
}

While this configuration works for simple copy operations, I need to extend the task to process the files (e.g., applying transformations to the file content). I’m not sure how to:

Modify this task to perform a transformation on the file content (e.g., replacing certain strings within the text files).
Ensure that the task only runs when the input files change (incremental build).
Define proper @Input and @Output annotations (if necessary) to ensure that Gradle tracks dependencies correctly.

What I've tried:

Custom Task for Transformation: I tried creating a custom task using tasks.register("processTextFiles") { ... } and iterating over files manually using fileTree. However, I’m unclear on the correct way to apply transformations to file content within Kotlin DSL.

tasks.register("processTextFiles") {
    val inputDir = file("src/main/text")
    val outputDir = file("build/processed-text")
    
    doLast {
        inputDir.walk().forEach { file ->
            if (file.extension == "txt") {
                val content = file.readText()
                val processedContent = content.replace("oldString", "newString")
                File(outputDir, file.name).writeText(processedContent)
            }
        }
    }
}

This works but I feel like it’s not idiomatic Kotlin DSL and doesn't leverage Gradle's capabilities for input/output tracking.

Incremental Build: I read that Gradle's incremental build feature relies on proper usage of @Input and @Output, but I’m unsure how to annotate these properties correctly for my custom task. I tried using inputs.dir(inputDir) and outputs.dir(outputDir), but the task still runs every time I build, even when the input hasn’t changed.

Task Type: I also tried extending the DefaultTask class to create a fully custom task, but ran into issues with property declarations and accessing files within the task action.


Environment:

Gradle version: 8.2

Kotlin version: 1.8.10

Android Gradle Plugin: 8.1.0


Thank you in advance for your help!


I’m not sure how to:



Modify this task to perform a transformation on the file content (e.g., replacing certain strings within the text files).


You can use the filter method (docs):
tasks.register<Copy>("processTextFiles") {
    filter { eachLineInFile ->
        eachLineInFile.replace("%SOME_PLACEHOLDER%", "someValue")
    }
}

The lambda is called with each line in the file and replaced with the return value of the lambda.


Ensure that the task only runs when the input files change (incremental build).
Define proper @Input and @Output annotations (if necessary) to ensure that Gradle tracks dependencies correctly.


Gradle will do all this for you based on the locations passed to the from and into methods because of the way the Copy task is written.
